# Bigcommerce product image customization with text change

Tags: image, customization, product, preview, bigcommerce

Currently I am trying to build such customization of product in Bigcommerce Storefront that allows to display image with dynamic text, which was entered in Textbox. That means product image preview should be shown INSTANTLY with new image with written text.

so that the end user will know how the final product will looks like and also same image should go in shopping cart as well.

I know that there is an app on Shopify named as Product Builder.

Is this possible to do it on Bigcommerce?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible with some fairly advanced client-side code.  Unfortunately I don't know of any plug and play systems or apps for Bigcommerce that will achieve what you're looking for, but there are a couple ways to get a live updating product preview if you're willing to get your hands dirty.

Here's an [example from my site](https://www.theelegantoffice.com/products/black-leatherette-desk-pad-wout-rails-34x20/).  Click the button under "personalize this item", and you'll see a live preview image like you describe in the modal.  Enter some text and change the monogram style and color, the preview image should update pretty quickly every time you change an option.  A solution exactly like mine may not be feasible for you, since that site is using a pretty complex React/Redux implementation built on an extensively customized Stencil theme... it's far from a turnkey solution.  That said, you could implement something similar without needing a totally custom app.

The image preview itself in the example above is powered by [IMGIX.com](https://www.imgix.com).  They offer a great service at a fantastic price.  Basically my system translates the user-selected Bigcommerce option into a URL string per IMGIX's URL-based API.  Displaying the live preview is then as simple as changing the image's src attribute to the corresponding IMGIX URL on every input change.  I do this in a React component that consumes a Redux store, but something similar could definitely be done in the framework of your choice, or plain old vanilla JavaScript.  Cloudinary offers a similar (maybe even a little bigger) feature set to IMGIX, but I found IMGIX to be a bit faster, and the pricing was considerably less for my usage.

You could also write something that uses the HTML5 canvas to overlay text and effects on an image, and thereby avoid using a third-party service.  I found such a solution to be way more work and way more taxing on the client-side device, but it'd definitely be another way to skin the proverbial cat.

There may be other viable solutions out there, but the above has been my experience in implementing something similar to what you're looking for on Bigcommerce.  I hope this is helpful!